# Jasmine Test case for Angular UI grid onRegisterApi funtion

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm writing Jasmine Unit test for AngularJS UI grid. 
I have a below UI grid function in my controller 
**Code:**

```
$scope.gridOption.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi) {
$scope.gridApi.core.on.sortChanged($scope, function(grid, sortColumns) {};
gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged($scope, function(newPage, pageSize) {};
};
```

I dont know how to write Unit test case for this function & internal private funtions....

Any one can help me on this?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You cannot unit tests methods that are not declared on the scope** or accessible via properties. Some people use _ to namespace private methods.

And it makes sense - you're testing the final output, you're not testing the "internals" - internals are either external libs which are unit tested themselves, either private methods that you could push via different params of public methods (otherwise they their existence is questionable).

If external action simulation is your target, then just use spies: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0EXBpsz9Bwc

**UPDATE - sample for service testing**

```
describe('myService', function () {
  'use strict';

  beforeEach(function () {
    // module that we are testing
    module('appServices');
  });

  it('myMethodName - should return empty array if called with null', inject(function (myService) {
    expect(myService.myMethodName(null)).toBe([]);
  }));
});
```

Ctrl testing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZp9Hz3bHZE .

There's a full suite of videos there - just download/copy the code and run locally to see exactly the use-cases. **Spies would basically allow you to hi-jack a request to an external service/reference and mock the response** - so when your method calls that external service, instead of actually calling that service, it will instead return your response and therefore you can asses what should the method return or not.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to $compile ui-grid and then scope.digest, this way you will have access to gridApi methods in your tests, for example:

```
scope.myGridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
```

**Update**

Step 1.

`createMycontroller(); // after you have configured and injected dependencies`

Step 2. Compile ui grid:

```
var gridContainer = "< div ui-grid="myGridOptions" ui-grid-pagination></div>";

var grid = $compile(gridContainer)(scope); // I've declared scope before as scope = $rootScope.$new();

scope.$digest();
```

At this stage ui grid should be compiled in my case myGridApi is in scope

Step 3 trigger paginationChanged through raise method.

```
scope.myGridApi.pagination.raise.paginationChanged();
```

I found raise method in ui grid unit tests:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/9d1a0b46e54983e09e0be8f89f9fac0ee74046e4/test/unit/core/factories/GridApi.spec.js#L26
and as part of the api docs:

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridApi

When you register an event it will:

"The event will get a .raise and .on prepended to it 
.raise.eventName() - takes no arguments"

Step 4 Set your expects

Comment: "First"? You only described one step, should this be a complete solution to OP's question?

Comment: I think the next steps depend on the context, I was dealing with a similar situation and after I compiled ui-grid in my tests, i was able to access its functions and properties. I thought that knowing a first step could be helpful. If later i cover all my coverage I will be able to extend my answer.